Trouble with Python Selenium Key Press
I'm trying to set up some batch look-ups using the orthographic dictionary here. Normally this requires one to type in the search box on the left and then click the "пошук" button beneath it:

There are three elements that seem relevant to me.
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_tsearch")
search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_search")
current_word = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "word_style")

The first is the search bar input element; the second is the search (пошук) button below it; and the third corresponds to the element that contains the searched word in the populated result on the right side of the page:

I tried simulating a key-press per the answer here, but the following code did not seem to change the result from "привіт" (the default value) to the searched word "людина". If anyone is able to see what I've messed up, I'd appreciate the help:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/"

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get(url)

search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_tsearch")
search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_search")

search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("людина")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_button).click(search_button).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

current_word = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "word_style")
print(current_word.text) # привіт, not людина


Issue is that your selenium script is too fast to read the printed text. Your selenium script should just wait for few milliseconds after clicking the button until you read the text.
Option 1: Just add a little wait in between clicking the search button and getting the text as below:
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_button).click(search_button).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(2)
current_word = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "word_style")

Imports you will need:
import time

Option 2: Use Selenium's waits as below:
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_button).click(search_button).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
current_word = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='люди́на ']"))))

Imports you will need:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ON ANOTHER NOTE: You don't really need to perform Key Press actions. .click() should be enough. You can change the code as below:
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_button).click(search_button).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_button).click(search_button).perform()


Thanks I'll try this when I get home tonight
